# Is there any kind of internship at the U.E.A? Are there any Esperanto related internships anywhere at all?

Tags: esperanto-speakers

I am a few months away from college and am looking for some possible internships in my areas of interest. Esperanto being one of my largest areas of interest, I pose the question above. 
Thank-you all for your time.
Dankon!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this: [UEA aĉetos loĝejon en Roterdamo](http://www.liberafolio.org/2016/uea-acetos-logejon-en-roterdamo)

I know that there was a call for volunteers at the end of last year/beginning of this year to come work and live in Rotterdam for a minimum of 3 months and up to a year, starting around October this year, and some "poŝmono" was going to be provided. I believe that this house mentioned in the above article has something to do with that; the news of it came out around the same time as I saw the call for Rotterdam volunteers. I have no idea what the current situation may be regarding those.

I think the Esperantic Studies Foundation (Montreal) and the New York office (for relations with the UN) are also looking for a part-timer or a volunteer to help with the administration of their financial affairs, or were in the past. All of these statements I am making come from conversations I had with people several months ago, however, so someone else can probably give you some better information. But yes, such opportunities do exist. I also remember seeing an Evildea video where he mentioned being offered a job somewhere in China when he was on a trip there, I don't recall if it was for El Popola Ĉinio, ĈRI, or somewhere else.

Your best method for finding these things is probably to keep contacting people and organizations and asking around. I think alot of news and opportunities like these in Esperantujo circulate by word of mouth, and unfortunately some organizations don't make heavy use of the internet for this kind of thing. Personally I have no experience working or volunteering for (or even being a member of) any Esperanto organization so I hope somebody who does will reply.